# log4j2.properties syslog is not wrking

Tags: properties, log4j2, syslog, rsyslog, appender

My java application problem is that log4j2 syslog is written not in 'local1.log' but
'messages'.
My /etc/rsyslog.conf is configured 'local1.*  /var/log/local1.log' in /etc/rsyslog.conf.

But One of weired is when I removed 'appender.syslog.layout.type' and 'appender.syslog.layout.pattern' from log4j2.properties, syslog starts being written in /var/log/local1.log correctly.

Is my configuration incorrect?

Are layout properties not applied in syslog?

[/etc/rsyslog.conf]

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local1.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

...

local1.*                                                /var/log/local1.log
```

[Used log4j2 library]

```
log4j-api-2.17.2.jar
log4j-core-2.17.2.jar
```

[log4j2.properties]

```
status = warn
name = Test

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss} %5p (%c{1} - %M:%L) - %m%n

appender.syslog.type = Syslog
appender.syslog.name = sysLogger
appender.syslog.host = localhost
appender.syslog.port = 514
appender.syslog.protocol = UDP
appender.syslog.facility = LOCAL1
appender.syslog.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.syslog.layout.pattern = %c{1} (%M:%L) %m\n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = consoleLogger, sysLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.syslog.ref = sysLogger
```

Answer (score 3):

Log4j2's syslog layout is used to format the **entire** syslog message and must therefore be one of [`SyslogLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#SyslogLayout) (traditional BSD syslog format) or [`Rfc5424Layout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#RFC5424Layout) (modern syslog layout). Using any other layout will result in invalid messages and RSyslog will have to guess the message's metadata. Most notably the facility will be set to `USER`.

If you want to send additional data to syslog, beyond `%m`, you should use the RFC5424 format and send the additional information as [structured data](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424#section-6.3). For example you can use (in XML format):

```xml
<Syslog name="sysLogger" host="localhost" port="514" protocol="UDP">
  <Rfc5424Layout appName="MyApp" facility="LOCAL1">
    <LoggerFields enterpriseId="32473" sdId="location">
      <KeyValuePair key="logger" value="%c" />
      <KeyValuePair key="class" value="%C" />
      <KeyValuePair key="method" value="%M" />
      <KeyValuePair key="line" value="%L" />
    </LoggerFields>
  </Rfc5424Layout>
</Syslog>
```

which translates to the properties format as:

```
appender.syslog.type = Syslog
appender.syslog.name = sysLogger
appender.syslog.host = localhost
appender.syslog.port = 514
appender.syslog.protocol = UDP
appender.syslog.layout.type = Rfc5424Layout
appender.syslog.layout.facility = LOCAL1
appender.syslog.layout.appName = MyApp
appender.syslog.layout.fields.type = LoggerFields
appender.syslog.layout.fields.enterpriseId = 32473
appender.syslog.layout.fields.sdId = location
appender.syslog.layout.fields.0.type = KeyValuePair
appender.syslog.layout.fields.0.key = logger
appender.syslog.layout.fields.0.value = %c
...
```

Virtually all modern syslog servers can interpret structured data. For RSyslog you need to:

1. Enable structured data parsing:

   ```
   module(load="mmpstrucdata")
   action(type="mmpstrucdata")
   ```
2. Create a template to format your message:

   ```
   template(name="MyAppFormat" type="list") {
       property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
       constant(value=" ")
       property(name="hostname")
       constant(value=" ")
       property(name="syslogtag")
       constant(value=" ")
       property(name="$!rfc5424-sd!location@32473!class")
       constant(value=" (")
       property(name="$!rfc5424-sd!location@32473!method")
       constant(value=":")
       property(name="$!rfc5424-sd!location@32473!line")
       constant(value=") ")
       property(name="msg" droplastlf="on")
       constant(value="\n")
   }
   ```
3. Use the template for messages coming from "MyApp":

   ```
   :app-name, isequal, "MyApp" {
       /var/log/myapp.log;MyAppFormat
       stop
   }
   ```